# Passing two data schema intent for ACTION_SHOW

Tags: java, android, schema

How can I to show all applications which to work with this schema which I pass in intent chooser. For example what I need:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google://test"));
intent.setData(Uri.parse("microsoft://test"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chooser"));
```

Comment: Default the android would show all avaibla application to handle the required action.
Also you can see 


intent.createChooser(title,target);

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way to do that by such way

```
    int x;
   // {set value for x using AlertDialog or whatever you prefer }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    if (x=0){

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("google://test"));

    } else if(x=1) {

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("microsoft://test"));

    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chooser"));
```